# Bash line break at every integer followed by specific string

Tags: bash, sed

How do I break a line at every integer followed by letter `Q` and an integer?

For example:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum Que Q94 dolor sit amet, Q3004 consectetur adipiscing
elit. Q1 Idcirco enim non desideraret" | sed -e $'s/Q\([0-9]\)/\\\nQ\1/g'
```

generates the following - incorrect - result:

```
Lorem ipsum Que   
Q4 dolor sit amet,   
Q004 consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Q Idcirco enim non desideraret
```

Note how the first integer digit is missing after each `Q`.

The expected result is:

```
Lorem ipsum Que   
Q94 dolor sit amet,   
Q3004 consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Q1 Idcirco enim non desideraret
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you are tired like me about all those sed variations (gnu,freebsd,open bsd, macos) there is a solution: Use `perl -pe` replacement.
Works the same in all machines and syntax is almost identical to gnu sed.
So this is tested in Debian, and will work fine also in your machine:

```
echo "...." |perl -pe 's/Q([0-9])/\nQ\1/g'
```

Comment: ... or a bit shorter `perl -pe 's/(Q\d)/\n$1/g'` :)

Comment: @jm666 Great tip! Thanks!

Comment: @jm666: Or, given that there's no need to use a capture group at all: `perl -pe 's/Q\d/\n$&/g'`.

Comment: @mklement0 - ah, yes!... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `$'...'` (an [ANSI C-quoted Bash string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)) suggests that you're using *BSD/macOS* `sed`, where use of escape sequence `\n` isn't supported in the replacement string.

To avoid confusion between `\`-prefixed escape sequences interpreted by `$'...'` up front and those interpreted by `sed`, I suggest using `$'\n'` *selectively*, by splicing it into the `sed` script exactly where needed:

```
... | sed 's/Q[0-9]/\'$'\n''&/g'
```

- `\` is needed in the replacement string to escape a *literal* newline,
- which is what ANSI C-quoted string `$'\n'` produces (by the time `sed` sees the script).

  - Note that *GNU* `sed` *does* support `\n` in the replacement string, which would simplify the command to: `... | sed 's/Q[0-9]/\n&/g'`
- Replacement-string placeholder `&` represents *everything* the regex matched (per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)).

  - This makes it unnecessary to define a *capture group*, as you tried, and which caused your problem in tandem with `$'...'` (see below).

---

As for **what you tried**:

The extra layer of escaping introduced by use of `$'...'` "ate" the `\` chars. in `Q\([0-9]\)`, so that `sed` saw `Q([0-9])`, which - in the absence of nonstandard option `-E` to activate *extended* regexes (EREs) - caused `(` and `)` to be treated as *ordinary* characters (which they are in a [*basic* regular expression (BRE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which `sed` uses by default).

Thus, *no capture group was defined*, and `\1` in the replacement string expanded to the *empty string*.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed

```
sed 's/Q\([0-9]\)/\nQ\1/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/Q[0-9]/\n&/g'
```

Comment: You need to advise that this solution works only with GNU Sed and not other versions of sed (like freebsd sed, openbsd sed, mac os sed, etc). Judging by the sed syntax in OP, it seems that OP is not using GNU Sed so this solution will not work in his machine, unless he decides to install gnu sed.